# update resource value in runtime .Net core (satellite assembly recompile in run time) with out stopping project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have resource.fa-IR.resx file and I use it to make my web site more flexible (with some keys and value)
my goal is admin can change value according to his requirement
I have a method that get key and value parameter and update the resource file , but it dose not effect before stop project and rebuild.

when I start it again my value changed.

I want my resource value to change in run time with out stopping project
Because I have a form to edit value or create new key value in admin panel
but changes are ineffective...

Comment: "my goal is admin can change value" when? During compile time? When the app is deployed, and while the app is stopped or running?

Comment: @gunr2171 when app is running

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676312/modifying-resx-file-in-c-sharp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218777/can-i-edit-resource-file-at-runtime

Comment: Could you please share us how have you configured that? For changing value in runtime how are you manipulating those value within your application code could you please share?